# Get JSONobject from JSONArray in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have JSONArray with different JSONObjects in it. When my method will be called at that time first JSONObject will be created. When again that method will be called then another JSONObject will be called beside the previous JSONObject. Now i want the element from the latest JSONObject inserted. And the problem is that JSONObject is inserted anywhere in JSONArray. So how can i get the element of latest JSONObject inserted.
Here is my JSONArray

```
[
    {
        "letter": "E",
        "col": 2,
        "row": 5,
        "badge": "1"
    },
    {
        "letter": "D",
        "col": 2,
        "row": 6,
        "badge": "2"
    },
    {
        "letter": "Y",
        "col": 2,
        "row": 8,
        "badge": "3"
    }
]
```

In above JSONArray i want the letter from the latest JSONObject created in android. I have done following things in my code but i am not getting proper letter as JSONObject is placed anywhere.

```
JSONArray jarry1 = new JSONArray(allwordsss);
for (int i = 0; i < jarry1.length(); i++) {
    String all = jarry1.getString(i).toString();
    Log.e("TAG2", "All" + all);
    JSONObject jobjjjj = new JSONObject(all);
    letter = jobjjjj.getString("letter");
}
Log.i("TAG2", "letter" + letter);
```

Comment: Please expand your question to include what you've tried so far, and which if any json library you are using.

Comment: I have updated my post please look AT it..And i am getting data from server..

Comment: You can't know which jsonobject is put in the array last, unless you store it somewhere. And please clarify what you're saying. To me, you're not making that much sense.

Comment: A JSONArray is an ordered sequence of values (objects), so depends on how your code builds that array.

Comment: @stealthjong-Yes i don't know where JSONObject is inserted. So if latest JSONObject is created somewhere in JSONArray then how to get letter from latest JSONObject.

Answer (score 3):

Try this it will help you.

```
try{
    JSONArray jarry1 = new JSONArray(allwordsss);
    JSONObject jobject
    for(int i=0; i<jarry1.size(); i++)
    {
       jobject = jarry1.getJSONObject(i)
       String letter = jobject.get("letter")
       Log.i("TAG", "letter" + letter);
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
 }
```

Comment: I simply don't know that where JSONObject is inserted.So i can't use this

Answer (score 1):

to access to the latest letter in your array:

```
String letter;
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(array.length()-1);

    if (object.has("letter")) // according to defensive programming rules
          letter = object.getString("letter");
catch {
    letter = "error...";
}
```

Comment: I simply don't know that where JSONObject is inserted.So  i can't use this.

Comment: you can handle order on server-side. add counter or 'CreatedDate' to each element

Answer (score 1):

Try following code, You can get whether specific json object is available in response json or not. If yes then get it.

```
 try{
    JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray(allwordsss);
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonResult = results.getJSONObject(i);

                // To check whether such key available or not, otherwise will through exception
                if (jsonResult.has("letter")) 
                     String letter = jsonResult .getString("letter");

          }
 }catch(JSONException e){
 }
```

Comment: I simply don't know that where JSONObject is inserted.So i can't use this.